# window application registration issue in vb6

Tags: vb6

i want to register my application when it first time runs. it will ask a serial number and 16 digit key after entering correct key it will register. when next time i run the application it will not ask me a register key. i want the code in vb6

Answer (score 1):

You might check out [Activelock](http://www.activelocksoftware.com/).  It's an open-source software licensing/copy protection system.  According to the site:

ActiveLock is a "totally" free COM DLL created to help you to:

- Add registration features,
- Protect your programs from piracy
- Sell your programs online!
- ActiveLock is powerful, flexible and
  100% royalty-free.

Another option, if you insist on VB6 code is [WLock-Licensing](http://www.fileguru.com/WLock-Licensing-Source-Code-For-VB6/info).

Comment: Important to note that it uses the BSD licence, which has no "copyleft" and allows linking from code with a different licence. I wouldn't put it past someone to create an open source copy-protection system with a "viral" licence like GPL :)